# Check if an associative array is empty

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array of id. In the controller I want to check if the array received is empty or not. I have written the following code for it but it does not work.

```
$product1=$_POST['id'];
$productString = implode(" ",$product1);
echo $productString; 
if(is_null($productString)){
   echo "No Values";
}else {
    echo "Values are present";
}
```

I have tried with empty() as well but in all the case even if there are no values in the array, which I am converting into a string, it says values are present. 
There are 5 fixed rows in my table in the view file, so, even if the values are empty the array output shows

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
)
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: `is_null()` checks whether a variable is NULL or not

Comment: If `empty($product1)` doesn't return true, then do a var_dump of that variable and and check what it actually contains. Add the output to your question. We have no idea what you're posting so we cant even guess what's going on.

Comment: @VinhVO - Read the last sentence in the question. The OP says that `empty()` doesn't work (which is what that post suggests using).

Comment: @mickmackusa - If the question is lacking proper info (like this one), I don't wait more than a few minutes. I mean, if the OP doesn't read the guidelines, like [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting, it's on them. :-) If they update it, I remove the close vote.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, well I did read the whole question. The linked one is supposed to answer "How to _Check if an associative array is empty_". While the OP has another problem than checking an array is empty or not. It's _checking all elements in the arrays is null or not_, instead. I also think as what mickmackusa does: _Why isn't my code working_

Comment: I am checking if the five rows in the table contains ids or not. If any id is present then update function will fire and if none of the table rows contain id then save function should fire. In order to do that, I am trying to find if the Id array is empty or not, but the array happens to be an associative array.

Comment: The situation is as such that I can't do that, it has to be checked after the form is submitted.

Comment: This is when there are no id values array ( 0 => '', 1 => '', 2 => '', 3 => '', 4 => '', ). If this is the output then echo should result "No values found". If any id is present then the var dump is array ( 0 => '1', 1 => '2', 2 => '', 3 => '', 4 => '', ). In this case the echo should be "Values are there".

Comment: I am assuming your program will do more than just identify if there is a number in your array of ids.  What is the next step?  `array_filter()` is fine, but it is a functional iterator.  If you are going to perform another loop, it would be better just to assess and handle in one loop.

Comment: @mickmackusa - This feels like a rabbit hole. I'm gonna step back before I fall in too deep. :-)

Comment: Please update your question to include all commented details; then please delete your comments.  This puts the full story all in one place (the right place).

Comment: @mickmackusa - Wow. You got patience! :-) Or did you fall in?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `implode` it means you are converting array to string. You can check if string is empty by `trim( $productString ) == ""`

```
$product1 = array( 0 => '', 1 => '', 2 => '', 3 => '', 4 => '' );
$productString = implode(" ",$product1);
if( trim( $productString ) == "" ){
      echo "No Values";
}else {
     echo "Values are present";
}
```

---

If by empty, you mean all of the elements of the array is empty string, you can use `array_filter` to remove all empty elements first.

```
$product1 = array( 0 => '', 1 => '', 2 => '', 3 => '', 4 => '' );
$product1 = array_filter( $product1 ); /* Remove all empty elements */

if(  count( $product1 ) == 0 ){
      echo "No Values";
}else {
     echo "Values are present";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `empty` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php for check emptiness of array. But you have empty rows into your $_POST['id'] array, for remove this row you should filter this rows by array_filter http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

```
$ids = array_filter($_POST['id']);
if (empty($ids)){
    echo "No Values";
}else {
    echo "Values are present";
}
```